# Flutter Web-stable reducing my hard drive space everytime i run the web app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I recently upgraded my flutter version from beta to flutter stable 2.2.2 However, everytime I run the flutter-web app that am creating, the size of my hard drive keeps reducing!!What could be the cause of this? Is

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because each time you debug or run a flutter code a flutter.tools.**** folder will be created in your temp folder which will be automatically created but not deleted by flutter you will have to delete them in order to save your disk space. This is what i did and nearly reduced 15.4 gb.

If you are using a windows machine then open Run software and run the command %TEMP% it will take you to the folder.

If you are using mac sorry i am not used to it and dosent know where it will be stored

but despite of the machine whenever you run the flutter program it will create a file and that is what eats up your space.

Hope this helps

Comment: This sorted my issue

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to change the temp folder location like a symlink or something like that if possible so that I can make it use a larger hard drive partition ? because in my case it gets exhausted quickly after a few builds have run and I have to do this process repeatedly. Thanks.

Comment: when my mac (11.6.7 Big Sur) ran out of disk running flutter apps the error message provided a clue to the location of these temp folders. For me they live in `/private/var/folders/hk/zjgnjbp90nsbzqm3wb74cyc40000gn/T` which I assume will vary for others. They were also much smaller than @Yagav's ~15Gb total such that I left them alone. Also for me they're `flutter_tools.*****` underscore, no dot.