# Flutter web is eating up my storage space on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, flutter, ubuntu, flutter-web

Flutter web is eating up my storage space. Every time, on my Ubuntu, I run my app on Chrome using `flutter run` command, my storage space gets reduced. To the best of my understanding, flutter creates some temporary folders but doesn't delete them. [Flutter Web-stable reducing my hard drive space everytime i run the web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68204150/flutter-web-stable-reducing-my-hard-drive-space-everytime-i-run-the-web-app). The answer given in the link works only for Windows, but doesn't for Linux (Ubuntu). How could I free up my space? Any help? `flutter clean` doesn't work either.

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` from the terminal of that project and see if it cleans up any of that space?

Comment: Yes, I did, quite a few times and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a comment on an [answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68204392/15432429).

The answer should be the same for you on Linux.  You need to find folders with name `flutter_tools.******` e.g. `flutter_tools.Gb0Kgb`.

The Windows folders appear to replace the underscore with a dot so search for that too. e.g `flutter.tools.******`

On my mac they're in a system temp location of `/private/var/folders/hk/zjgnjbp90nsbzqm3wb74cyc40000gn/T` which may indicate a likely location for you.

Happy hunting!

Comment: Yep, fixed the issue. 'tmp' is the folder Flutter is creating all its temporary folders in. Kudos